# hmset is not a function in node

Tags: node.js, redis

I am running node.js 16 and redis 5.0
When I try to connect to redis I can run commands like info
but when I try to run hmset I get an error saying it is not a function.

```
Welcome to Node.js v16.13.2.
Type ".help" for more information.
> const redis = require("redis");
undefined
> const client = redis.createClient();
undefined
> client.connect()
Promise {
  <pending>,
  [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 98,
  [Symbol(trigger_async_id_symbol)]: 5,
  [Symbol(destroyed)]: { destroyed: false }
}
> client.hmset("hi", "foo", "bar", "hello", "world");
Uncaught TypeError: client.hmset is not a function
```

Any guidance on how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `hset` function; it has the same functionalities.

[HMSET](https://redis.io/commands/hmset/) command in Redis is deprecated in favor of [HSET](https://redis.io/commands/hset/) command.